# Insertion of treemap by one comparator and getting an entry based on another comparator in java

Tags: java, treemap

```
 class Person
  {

  int id;
  String name;
  }
```

I want to create a TreeMap . The comparator used is

`Comparator<Person>  comp = (e1, e2) -> e1.name.compareTo(e2.name);`

So I will get a ascending sorted treemap based on name attribute of person.

But I want to update the TreeMap based on id attribute of element because id is the unique element. So if I get a Person object, I should get the
      key-value pair based on id not name. How will it be possible?

Comment: Why don't you simply change it to `id` instead of name ?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the Comparator to first compare by names and then by ID :

```
Comparator<Person>  comp = (e1, e2) -> {
    int res = e1.name.compareTo(e2.name);
    if (res == 0)
        return Integer.compare(e1.id,e2.id);
    else
        return res;
};
```

This will ensure ordering by name, as well as uniqueness determined by both name and id (i.e. two elements must have the same name and id in order to be considered the same element). This is assuming that if two `Person`s have the same `id`, they also have the same `name`.

Answer (score 0):

A `TreeMap` can have only one comparator.

What you actually need here is two `TreeMap` objects, one that maps names to `Person` objects, and the other than maps ids to `Person` objects.

When you add or remove entries in one map, you need to make the corresponding change to the other one.